# Back-off restarting failed container(K8S)

Tags: docker, kubernetes

When I run my deployment.yaml file with below command
**kubectl apply -f XXXX-depl.yaml** this command run the pod for some times When I check with **kubectl get pods**  . The status for pod will be **CrashLoopBackOff**.

When I check **kubectl describe pod [podname]** I can see this **error Back-off restarting failed container** . not able to resolve this.

Docker engine version :v20.10.17
Got some suggestion we need to adjust periodSeconds or timeoutSeconds. I am confused where in deployment file we need to adjust these 2 fields.

Comment: Kubernetes is unable to get your container running, so you need to investigate why the container will not run before you start adjusting values. It may also be that you have startup/ready probes defined that do not actually tell k8s the container is running and thus it will continually try to restart the container.

Comment: You may find this article useful: [Fix CrashLoopBackOff](https://komodor.com/learn/how-to-fix-crashloopbackoff-kubernetes-error/#:~:text=If%20you%20get%20the%20back,window%20of%20time%20to%20respond)

Comment: `kubectl logs [podname]` will print the logs. You can investigate further from that point.